# Does authorea have any moderation for preprints submitted to it?

Tags: arxiv, preprint

Some of the preprint servers like arXiv have moderation. Others like viXra don't have any form of them.
I browsed  [authorea.com](http://authorea.com)  and I think they don't have any sort of moderation like viXra.
*Am I right?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked this question on their help chat.
This is the answer that I received

> Authorea preprints go through a basic screening (only content scholarly in nature is accepted in the repository).

So, you seem to be *wrong*.
There is moderation, although it seems to be lax in nature.
So, I probably think that your paper will get through it.
Authorea seems to be very new though. I checked it out thanks to you.
It seems to be some combination of overleaf and arXiv.